# Is there a reason of $\cos(11x)+\sin(11(x+1))\approx 0$

Tags: trigonometry

Is  there a reason of

> $$\cos(11x)+\sin(11(x+1))\approx 0$$

Comment: It seems that $\cos(11x) + \sin(11(x+1)) \approx 0$ even if $x$ is [not an integer](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=cos%2811x%29+%2B+sin%2811%28x%2B1%29%29), reaching a max and min of $\pm 0.0044$ (due to the fact that $11 \approx 3.5 \pi$).  This is necessarily the best bound we can put on the value of $\cos(11n)+\sin(11(n+1))$, even if we specify $n \in 2\Bbb Z_+$.

Comment: $11 \approx 3.5 \pi$, so $\sin(x) + \cos(x+11)$ is always close to zero.

Comment: @Arthur which is similar to saying $\pi \approx \dfrac{22}{7}$

Comment: It holds equally well for negative $n$, too.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Looking at the unit circle, one can see that $\sin(x+\frac{3\pi}{2}) = -\cos(x)$. Using the fact that trig functions are $2\pi$ periodic, $\sin(x+\frac{7\pi}{2})$ also equals $-\cos(x)$. Now, $\sin(11(n+1)) = \sin(11n + 11)$, and $11 \approx \frac{7\pi}{2}$, so $\sin(11n+11)\approx -\cos(11n)$. This relation in fact holds for any $n$, not just for integers.

Answer (score 6):

Note that
$$
11=\frac72\pi+\delta\tag{1}
$$
where $\delta=0.0044257124357$.

Therefore,
$$
\begin{align}
&\cos(11x)+\sin(11(x+1))\\[6pt]
&=\cos(11x)+\sin\left(11x+\frac72\pi+\delta\right)\\
&=\cos(11x)+\sin\left(11x+\frac72\pi\right)\cos(\delta)+\cos\left(11x+\frac72\pi\right)\sin(\delta)\\[6pt]
&=\cos(11x)-\cos(11x)\cos(\delta)+\sin(11x)\sin(\delta)\\[12pt]
&=\cos(11x)(1-\cos(\delta))+\sin(11x)\sin(\delta)\tag{2}
\end{align}
$$
Since the absolute value of a dot product is no more than the product of the lengths of the vectors, we get
$$
\begin{align}
\left|\cos(11x)+\sin(11(x+1))\right|
&\le\sqrt{(1-\cos(\delta))^2+\sin^2(\delta)}\\[6pt]
&=2|\sin(\delta/2)|\\
&=2\left|\sin\left(\frac{22-7\pi}4\right)\right|\\
&=0.004425708823779\tag{3}
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 3):

To make this slightly more explicit: let $f(n) = \cos(11n) + \sin(11(n+1))$.  Then you can write

$$f(n) = \cos (11n) + \sin (11n+11) $$

and using the addition formula for sine

$$f(n) = \cos (11n) + \sin 11n \cos 11 + \cos 11n \sin 11. $$

Rearranging a bit this is

$$f(n) = (\cos 11n) (1 + \sin 11) + (\sin 11n) \cos 11. $$

Now since $7\pi/2 \approx 11$, we have $\sin 11 \approx \sin 7\pi/2 = -1$ and $\cos 11 \approx \cos 7\pi/2 = 0$.